# Python helper function scope

Tags: python, function, scope, local-variables

So, I have a whole bunch of things doing basically the same thing with only a slight change in input. Perfect candidate to be function'd out and called each time with different parameters, right?

Apparently, python thinks I'm wrong.

So, here's a boiled-down version of my problem

```
def main():
    x = 10

    def helper(n):
      if (x > n):
          x -= n
```

There's dozens of other lines in the helper function, and it's called dozens of times in main, but these are the lines that are causing me the problem. I know that the helper function is using local scope instead of using the one from main, but my question is, why? and how do I fix it?

I don't want to make x global, I just want the helper to use the already existing x instead of making up its own. Without this helper function, the total number of lines of code is going to quadruple, at least, and the code will be a convoluted, unreadable mess.

EDIT: Also, Main uses x a whole bunch, so I can't just define it locally, in case that wasn't clear.

Comment: Are you getting an exception?  `UnboundLocalError` perhaps?

Comment: You can simply send `x` as a parameter to `helper()`...

Comment: @alfasin -- Possibly.  It really depends on what OP is expecting to happen with `x` (e.g. expecting x to be mutated inside the function but passing in an immutable object...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3 you can do this by putting `nonlocal x` in the inner function.  In Python 2 you can't do it.

However, what you can do instead is return the value from the helper function, and assign it where you call the helper function.  It's a little hard to tell from your example, but I'm assuming you're using it something like this:

```
def main():
    x = 10

    def helper(n):
        if (x > n):
            x -= n

    # do something that changes x
    helper(2)
    # now x has changed
```

Instead, do this:

```
def helper(x, n):
    if (x > n):
        return x - n
    else:
        return x

def main():
    x = 10

    # do something that changes x
    x = helper(x, 2)
    # now x has changed
```

The idea is to pass the helper function the values it needs, and have it return the resulting value, which you can then assign (or do what you like with) at the place where the helper is called.  This also often makes the code easier to follow, as opposed to having the helper function directly modify variables in its caller.  Also notice that here you can define `helper` outside `main`, creating a cleaner separation between the two, and also making `helper` available for use in other functions.

Comment: That's a good idea, but what if the case is that helper is changing more than one variable?

I might consider migrating my entire project to Python 3 just to use nonlocal...

Comment: @MatthewFournier The helper can return a tuple object containing multiple values, and in the main context you can assign the local objects to their new values with the returned tuple.

Comment: @MatthewFournier: Then you should have it return all the values it wants to affect.  However, the broader answer is "don't do that".  Having functions that modify lots of external state instead of returning values makes for code that is difficult to understand, maintain, and debug.  I suspect your actual function is rather baroque in structure and could be rewritten to avoid this sort of state-munging, but it's hard to know without knowing more about what you're actually doing.

Comment: All right, I've reworked my functions into only mutating one value. I'm marking this one as the answer then.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on the line:  `x -= n`.  Since you are doing an augmented assignment, python thinks (incorrectly) that `x` is a local variable.  Unfortunately, `x` is a "nonlocal" variable.  On python3.x, if you are OK with modifying `x` in the scope of `main`, then you can use the `nonlocal` keyword.  However, I'm guessing you don't want to modify `x` in `main`'s scope.  A cross-version trick is to get yourself a local variable with the same value as the non-local version:

```
def main():
    x = 10
    def helper(n):
        lx = x
        if x > n:
           lx -= n
        # etc., etc.

    helper(12)  # ...
```

If you really want to mutate `x` in the scope of `main`, you might want to consider a class (with `helper` a method on the class):

```
class Main(object):  # Main for lack of a better name...
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def helper(self, n):
        if self.x > n:
            self.x -= n

def main():
    x = Main(10)
    ...
    x.helper(12)
    ...
```

Comment: It's hard to tell from the example in the question, but I don't think this will do what the OP wants, because I think the OP is trying to use the helper to actually modify the `x` in the outer function.  Creating a new local inside `helper` will let you modify that new variable, but it won't "help" because it won't affect the `x` in `main`.

Comment: @BrenBarn -- Yeah, it is hard to tell.  I've updated with another alternative.

Comment: This _almost_ works. It's not giving an error and it's running properly, but it's not passing the `lx` value back to main afterwards.

Comment: @MatthewFournier -- Ahh, so you _do_ want to mutate the `x` in `main`.  In that case you need to return it from `helper` and re-bind it  e.g. `x = helper(n)` or use the class based approach (which might be more trouble than it is worth).

Comment: @mgilson -- Problem is, there's helpers that modify more than one variable.

Comment: @MatthewFournier -- Then the class based approach is almost certainly more along the lines of what you want.  You _could_ return everything that might be mutated in helper and unpack them all:  `x, y, z = helper(12)`, but then you start having quite a maintenance headache.